# How to execute a named pipeline with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created a pipeline named "statespl" in my Mongo database. How can I call it from Mongoose? So far I've just had to copy the code from the pipeline into my Node app but since it's named in the database surely there's a way to call it by name using Mongoose?

Comment: What do you mean by "I created a pipeline in my Mongo database"? Did you store the pipeline as text? Or did you create a view?

Comment: please be more specific about your question. Problem is unclear.